# Start Ecto for Mix task (Mix.EctoSQL.ensure_started not working anymore)

Tags: elixir, ecto

I know this question has been asked already and the answers were always individual answers.

However I've seen `Mix.EctoSQL.ensure_started` mentioned quite a bit and it seems as if this is the accepted way to do it.

However with `ecto_sql 3.1.2` this functionality has been completely removed (See the [commit](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/commit/70ff9f14878e161d8281fb83cd162f8e8b076d91)). It's not obvious to me why it has been removed.

So to sum this question up: is there an accepted way to start ecto, the repo and make sure the logging backend works as expected without writing too much custom code?

Comment: In the commit you linked to introduces `Ecto.Migrator.with_repo/2` as a replacement. Can you explain why that does not fit your requirements?

Comment: My question is about starting Ecto in a Mix task it's unrelated to the migrator of Ecto. There are two changes in the referenced commit. My question is solely related to the removal of `ensure_started`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current accepted way of doing this is with

```
Mix.Task.run("app.start")
```

`Mix.EctoSQL.ensure_started` was a private function, not meant to be used outside of EctoSQL. This new approach is the one [recommended by Jose](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1586#issuecomment-233301683) in its place.

It should be noted that this will start your entire application (including background workers or anything else your application would normally start) so you may want to modify your `application.ex` file to not start those when started by a mix task.